# What security risks are associated with exposing SQL schema in error messages?

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection, database-schema, code-injection

There's a web application that captures server errors and reports them to admins so the errors can be resolved.  These errors are the result of things happening at a lower level, in daemons, etc.; nowhere near the web layer.  Occasionally, a SQL statement that fails will bubble up to the error page, exposing some amount of database schema.

There's no correlation between the URI of the reporting page and the errors exposed.  If I understand correctly, I think that means the problem of SQL injections are avoided since there's no web path for injection, but want to confirm.

The users who can access these reports can also log in to the server itself and access the databases in question, so if we really want to know what the schema is, we have a way to view it.

Are there security risks to consider in this scenario?

Comment: SQL injection vulnerabilities can be exploited with a single shot without any errors at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think accepted practice is to log the error messages to a central place (could be the database) and have a routine that sanitizes message that gets shown to users to ensure that no sensitive information is shared.

Bad people can use knowledge about your system for nefarious purposes such as SQL Injection Attacks, Denial of Server attacks, etc.

https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/ERR01-J.+Do+not+allow+exceptions+to+expose+sensitive+information

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there is no reason why SQL errors should ever be exposed to the user, especially if this is a business user in front of a web application. That is why we have "catch" and "throw". The Inner Exception should only be bubbled up during debugging. Otherwise, it should be kept in the log.

Typically, we should monitor the log. If you rather wait for customer complaints (due to personnel limitation), you can certainly accompany the message that you "throw" with a tracking number that relates to your log to illustrate the nature of the problem.

If you work in "we're all friends here" environment, then there should be no problem potentially exposing the schema through the error message. But your concern about security already signals that this is not the case.

Comment: really? we have catch and throw for this purpose? What is the scenario of using them?

Answer (score 0):

First, to answer your question.

There is **always** a security risk. There is **no** useless data for the attacker. Even if one cannot serve you with a certain attack scenario on the plate, it doesn't mean there are no risks.

Next, on the idea of showing system error messages on the web front.

As others already stated it, it is a very bad idea in general. An innocent user don't have to see these technical details but a generalized error page only. Having them details revealed to the web visitor **is a bug**. Bugs better to be fixed. To fix a bug is a way better scenario than to ask on Stack Overflow is this bug critical or not.